# Making a video editor application in Flash

Tags: flash, video, editor

I'm wanting to build a project, it's an online video creation software in Flash so people could upload some music, choose videos from a library, edit the whole thing and export and download a movie in the end.
I've seen websites like www.Animoto.com close to what I want to do but I can't find how it's made and I'd like to make it a little more advanced when it come to editing.

Here is the design I'm thinking about for the flash video editor. 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1924937/video_editor%20copy.jpg
Is possible to build such a video editor in Flash?

David

Comment: Wow. Online non-linear video editing programs are difficult to get correct even when they run locally using native code. Remotely via a web site might be way too optimistic if this the question you're starting with..

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes it's possible. Sky is the limit but this question is too general.

Comment: ok great! So it's possible to put a few videos in one timeline just like in the screen shot and play around with the time bar?
Anywhere I cold find out how?
I understand how to play with 1 video with it's own timeline but I don't understand how to put 2 videos one after the other and still have one timeline in common.

Comment: @David you have to be more specific in your questions. This is not exactly the way stackoverflow works... Please consider going through the http://stackoverflow.com/faq Regards..